# Custom module name conflicts with unsupported contrib module -- how to avoid "This project is no longer supported" warning?

Tags: 9, .info

This Drupal 9 site runs a fork of the [search_file_attachments](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_file_attachments) module, modified for custom purposes, and for Drupal 9 compatibility.

For some time now, the Available updates report has shown, for this module, the warning "Project not supported: This project is no longer supported, and is no longer available for download. Disabling everything included by this project is strongly recommended!"

I intend to keep running this module as I might any other custom module, and would like Drupal to stop warning about this, on the rationale that this is no longer a contributed module in need of update status monitoring.

I've tried removing the d.o packaging info:

```
diff --git a/search_api_attachments.info.yml b/search_api_attachments.info.yml
index 2b2d3cf..adec8e7 100644
--- a/search_api_attachments.info.yml
+++ b/search_api_attachments.info.yml
@@ -3,12 +3,7 @@ name: 'Search API Attachments - Custom Fork'
 description: 'Extract and index file fields content.'
 core: 8.x
 core_version_requirement: ^8 || ^9
-package: Search
 configure: search_api_attachments.admin_form
 dependencies:
   - search_api:search_api
 
-# Information added by Drupal.org packaging script on 2020-04-04
-version: '8.x-1.0-beta16-custom-1'
-project: 'search_api_attachments'
-datestamp: 1586010934
```

I've also tried removing the composer.json file.

Both of these were followed by `drush cr` and then manually checking for updates with the "Check manually" link on the Available updates report, but the warning persists.

**Question:** Other than renaming the module (which I assume would solve the problem but is work I'd like to avoid), can I somehow instruct Drupal to stop checking for updates on this module?

Comment: You can also ask for co-maintainership and if the current maintainer isn't responding you can ask to take over the project. Would actually be better to get the D8+ version out instead of keeping it custom IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

The updates are checked via the core `update` module. The `update.manager` service allows a way to alter the list of projects it checks the data from via [`hook_update_projects_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21update%21update.api.php/function/hook_update_projects_alter/9.2.x). Technically the following should work:

```
function MODULENAME_update_projects_alter(&$projects) {
  // Hide the forked module from the list.
  unset($projects['search_api_attachments']);
}
```

Please make sure you replace the MODULENAME with the actual module name where you are implementing this hook.